# How do I continue to the second main2() from main()?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

I have a problem. Here is the simplified version:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
      cout << "Hello!";
      return 0;
     }
    string name = "My name is ______";
    int main2() {
      cout << name;
      return 0;
     }
```

I have tried to remove the first return 0; in the main(), but it did nothing. I want to somehow start main2() from main(). Is it possible?
I tried running the code(I use repl.it) and it didn't return any error messages. I also tried running it from the Terminal and it just prints Hello!.

Comment: You need to _call_ main2.

Comment: soo, how do i do that?

Comment: ... and declare it before `main`, as its definitions appears after `main`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you've just started learning C++, you might want to pick up a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) to get a solid foundation to build on.

Comment: Put `main2();` in your `main` then. In C++ you need to declare the function before you use it, so either put the entirety of `int main2()` before `int main` or put a prototype before `int main` by adding `int main2();`

Comment: I think part of the confusion here is due to misunderstanding the `main` function. `main` gets a special treatment, unlike other functions. The comprehensive details are complicated, but a good C++ book/tutorial should be able to address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Forward declare |main2|.
int main2();

int main() {
  cout << "Hello!";
  main2();
  return 0;
}
string name = "My name is ______";
int main2() {
  cout << name;
  return 0;
}
```

To elaborate on the differences between C++ and Python here: In C++ `main` is the [entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) for your program.  So in C++, you can think of the start of the `main` function as the equivalent of Python's "top of the file".  Your program will begin running at the top of `main`, and stop running at the end of it.  Anything that is not invoked starting from the `main` function (or transitively invoked) will not be executed.

Comment: You should `return main2();` rather than calling `main2` and returning 0.

Comment: It depends on what the goals of the program are.  It's not wrong to ignore the return value of `main2` and return our own 0.  Personally I would prefer it if `main2` were of return type `void`, but I wanted to keep things similar to the example code.

Comment: Just to say, this worked. Thank you Natah Rogers! I'll mark it as soon as I can.
"Avoid comments like +1 or Thanks!" oh well...

Comment: Returning `0` in a main indicates wheter your program has terminated correctly or not. So if you do `main2(); return 0;`, you indicates that the program has terminated correctly, even if `main2()` has failed. By doing `return main2();`, you forward the information from `main2` to the original caller. There are other ways to do so, but discarding the return value of `main2` is certainly not a good idea.

Comment: Sure, for `main` in particular that is true, however I would argue that `main2` "failing" vs "succeeding" here is nonsensical.

Comment: "nonsensical"? Why? `main2` returns an `int`, which appears to be an error code. Even if in this example the error code is meaningless, it is present, so you should not discard it...

Comment: I guess I just don't see the `int` it returns as something that "appears to be an error code".  I see it more as something that just shouldn't be there in the first place.  If the purpose here were to demonstrate handling/propagating an error code, then I would strongly prefer if the example code that did that at least had a path handling a legitimate error.

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote is roughly equivalent to the following Python:

```py
def main():
  print('Hello')
  return 0

name = 'My name is ____'

def main2():
  print(name)
  return 0

if __name__ == '__main__'
  sys.exit(main())
```

I believe now it's clear why `main2` never gets executed: it's never called.

Note that the `main` function in C++ is the one function which gets called automatically at program start, and exiting `main` terminates the program. Whatever you want to happen while your program is running must be called from within `main`.

Also note that a name (such as a function) must be declared before it can be used. So you'll have to either move the definition of `main2` before that of `main`, or at least declare `main2` there. Which you could do like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main2();

int main() {
  cout << "Hello!";
  return main2();
}

string name = "My name is ______";

int main2() {
  cout << name;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call main2() inside main():

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

        string name = "My name is ______";
        int main2() {
          cout << name;
          return 0;
         }

        int main() {
          cout << "Hello!";
          main2();
          return 0;
         }
```